# Ошибка в консоли ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Буду очень благодарен за помощь/совет! Спасибо! :)**

Решил добавить на сайт вот такое:
Весь код взять оттуда.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QXLyzE

Ругается на эту строку без подключения jQuery.

```
var totalSlideNumber = $(".background").length;
```

Ошибка такая:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Далее если подключу jQuery ругается на:

```
var mousewheelEvent = isFirefox ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "wheel";
window.addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, _.throttle(parallaxScroll, 60), false);
```

И ошибка вот такая:

```
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

Пробовал подключать в head jQuery первым и затем мой скрипт.
Пробовал в body подключать - итого тот же.

Подключал jQuery вот так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Проблема не в jQuery... `_` - переменные с такими названиями использует еще `lodash` - его тоже нужно подключить, `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js` . в CodePen, над блоком JS, слева есть шестеренка. Нужно нажать на неё, чтобы посмотреть все подключенные ссылки.

Comment: P.s. вы там учитывайте, что не у всех есть колесо мышки) Например на ноутах (хоть и есть, но неудобная)

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы мой спаситель! :)
Колесо мышки не у всех есть, с этим согласен.
Так что лучше не вставлять такое на сайт?